# How to convert http.get() to http.post() in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, http, post, get

I have following url in `http.get()` request

```
var ipaddress ="192.160.0.20";
var name = "root";
var pw ="root";
var loginUrl= "http://" + ipaddress + ":8080/managemind/user.cgi?ACTION=login&LOGIN=" + name + "&PASSWORD=" + pw + "&CLIENT_TYPE=mobile&SUBSCRIBER_ID=NotAssigned&MAC_ADDRESS=NotApplicable";
```

I am doing the following request using `get` and getting the response.

```
$http.get(createdUrl)
.then(function(response) {}
```

Now I want to convert my `get` request to `post` request.How to do ?

Comment: you're adding user credentials to your url (via query string), you need to pass it in the `post` body.

Comment: @AranS can you please answer the question in Answer section. I tried to do that but not able to pass..please guide me

Comment: What **exactly** needs to be in the POST request body (`data`) and what needs to be specified as a query parameter (`params`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending vulnerable data with `post` method it's advised to break apart your query string pass it in the request body. Like this:

```
var myUrlWithoutQueryString = ... // here goes your url   
var loginData = {
    name: ...
    ps: ...
    action ...
    // and so on
};

$http.post(myUrlWithoutQueryString, loginData);
```

Notice that the `loginData` you're passing should match the parsing requirements in the server-side (matching parameteres for instance).

Comment: *"you must break apart your query string"* <- That's not necessarily true. POST requests can have both query parameters and request body data. It's entirely up to the server-side application in how those pieces of data are interpreted.

Comment: Also, there's a good chance OP needs to send the POST body data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but that needs clarification

Comment: I agree @Phil, my mistake on the 'must break' part. Sending data through post request seems more legit, especially when sending user credentials. It is possible of course to sent params through query string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$http.post`

```
$http.post(createdUrl)
.then(function(response) {}
```

Comment: I am not getting any response

Comment: @MKY you'd be getting some sort of response, at the very least in your browser's *Network* console.